# Marquee from database in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, marquee

First, I used marquee with repeater and it is working fine, but it shows all data at the same time.

My code look like this :

```html
<marquee id="ml" style="text-align: center" width="400px" height="170"
               scrolldelay="5" scrollamount="5">
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("notification") %>'></asp:Label><br />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</marquee>
```

Here is my code behind page below:

```js
private void getnotification()
{
        DataTable notifydt = new DataTable();
        DateTime currentdt = DateTime.Now;
        string date1 = currentdt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        string qry = "";
        qry = "select notification from adminnotification where visibility=1 and FromDate >='" + date1 + "'";
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(qry, con);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        
        con.Open();
        sda.Fill(notifydt);
        int count = notifydt.Rows.Count;

        DataView dv = new DataView(notifydt);

        if (count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow DR in notifydt.Rows)
            {
                dv.RowFilter = "notification='" + DR["Notification"].ToString()+ "'";
            }
           
            Repeater1.DataSource = dv;
            Repeater1.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

I want to show data one by one, how can I do that ?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few things you can check

- The Repeater control has no horizontal or vertical "direction". You either need to control it via css:

  ```
  <ItemTemplate>
  <div style="float:left">
      <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("notification") %>' />
  </div>
  </ItemTemplate>
  ```

  or use other controls like DataList, where you could set direction

  ```
  <asp:DataList RepeatDirection="Horizontal" ... >
  ```
- The following filter makes no sense and needs to be deleted

  ```
  foreach (DataRow DR in notifydt.Rows)
  {
      dv.RowFilter = "notification='" + DR["Notification"].ToString()+ "'";
  }
  ```
- The filter by date could be set directly in sql. For example, if you use SQL Server then you could use the getdate() function

  ```
  where visibility=1 and FromDate >= getdate()
  ```

  To get only date you could use Convert(date, getdate()), see documentation for your database for more details.

Comment: Thank your dear for your answer. it is working fine , but i cant add white space between each rows .. How i can do that ?

Comment: Thank your ,also i solved the white space by using the property CellPadding="10" in DataList